# arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True not working for one dataset

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, copy

I am doing a basic copy from sde database to file geodatabase. I have a loop going through each feature dataset in the sde database, this loop is really basic it just uses `arcpy.Copy_Management` to copy everything over. I have `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` at the beginning of the script after importing in arcpy. It does not throw me that error for any other feature dataset, even though they are also overwriting a FeatureDataset with the same name.

the error it throws is  :

> ERROR 000605: Output Sidewalk already exists within
>   C:\Users\stack\Desktop\Testing\scripts\Dump.gdb\Sidewalk. Failed to
>   execute (Copy).

I even added `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` to the beginning to of the function. I also put a line in the exception the prints out the status of `env.overwriteOutput` and it is true at that time when it breaks.

This does not make any sense to me. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: In python `true` is a variable, `True` is the builtin [constant](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#True). Not sure if that's a typo on your part.

Comment: Yeah sorry thats a typo on my part. I have it True on my actual script

Comment: Are you using `from arcpy import env`? If not, you need to use the full `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput`.

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to add that part in. Yes im using arcpy.env.overwriteOutput its weird because this is the only dataset that is giving me this. All the other ones are also overwriting and they are perfectly fine overwriting

Comment: This is usually a lock issue. Make sure the feature class doesn't have a lock on it (generally caused by it being open in ArcMap or ArcCatalog, or as the result of another script).

Comment: No thats not it sadly, im going to try running it a few more times before choosing the delete before I copy method

Comment: That method works just as well: `if arcpy.Exists (fc): arcpy.Delete_management (fc)`

Comment: Yeah seems like that is the way I will have to do it. I just find it odd that only one feature dataset is giving me this problem.

Comment: I do see this behavior on occasion. I have given up trying to troubleshoot it and just use the check and delete method described by @EmilBrundage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this appears to be a bug of some sort. Use the workaround `Exists \ Delete` method:

```
if arcpy.Exists (fc): 
    arcpy.Delete_management (fc)
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I have been doing, thanks for submitting it as an answer for others though.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old, but I thought I'd add another solution that I figured out after coming across the same error just now, as it may help others that look here in future.

**Make sure that feature class is not in use anywhere else.**

In my case I had set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` but got the error `ExecuteError: ERROR 000258: Output C:\blah\blah\blah already exists` while that feature class was being displayed in ArcMap.  I then closed ArcMap, and ran the script again (in PyScripter) and the script worked fine with no errors.

NB:  ArcMap is very bad at hanging on to things it no longer needs.  In some cases removing a layer in ArcMap, or even opening a new blank map may not be enough.  You may have to actually close ArcMap completely.

Also, make sure the feature class is not being used by any other processes.  Eg, ArcCatalog, ArcGIS Server (eg in a map service), some other Python script, etc, etc.