# Failed to Copy SDE Dataset Error 000260 Using arcpy.Copy_management and arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I thought I could use the `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` to overwrite the existing datasets within my target SDE "JeffCoGIS.sde"; however, I get an error that states:

`ExecuteError: ERROR 000260: Failed to copy Database Connections\GISData.sde\GISData.DBO.GIS_Dept into Database Connections\JeffCoGIS.sde\GISData.DBO.GIS_Dept
ERROR 000260: Item with the same path name already exists.
Failed to execute (Copy).`

I am new to python and couldn't find any help in ESRI Resources on how to overwrite the datasets.  Some have mentioned to use replication; however, for our particular workflow, we need to pursue overwrite and copy, if I can get it to work.

Is there a different tool I should use?

If I run this script on the empty SDE, it works fine - just when trying to overwrite the existing datasets.

```
#Name:  Copy_JeffCoGIS_Rev2.py
#Copy all datasets including the feature classes within each dataset from
#    SDE database "GISData.sde" to SDE database "JeffCoGIS.sde"
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections\\GISData.sde"

fcList = arcpy.ListDatasets()
#print fcList

for dataset in fcList:
    arcpy.Copy_management(dataset, "Database Connections\\JeffCoGIS.sde\\"+ 
    dataset)
```

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/158773/43

Comment: It is not working for all datasets; however, I did look up that link as well, but am not sure where the appropriate place in my script is to place it since I am working with a list (multiple datasets).

Comment: You would put inside your loop - `if arcpy.Exists (dataset): arcpy.Delete_management (dataset)`

Answer (score 1):

When copying try:

```
arcpy.Copy_management(dataset, "Database Connections\\JeffCoGIS.sde\\" + dataset.split(".")[1])
```